# Automatically echo the result of an assignment statement in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

Is there a way to make IPython automatically echo the result of an assignment statement?

For example, in [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), ending an assignment statement without a semicolon prints the result of the assignment, and putting a semicolon at the end of the statement suppresses any output.

```
>> b=1+2

b =

     3

>> b=1+2;
>>
```

I want to be able to do something similar in IPython.  However, currently I have to use two separate statements if I want to see the assignment result:

```
In [32]: b=1+2

In [33]: b
Out[33]: 3
```

Comment: Late comment, but his is one of the things I miss the most from Matlab in IPython. There is currently a [feature request](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/93) open for adding something similar to IPython notebooks, but nothing has been implemented yet.

Comment: Closed to a newer dupe since there have been recent developments in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment is purely a statement in Python, so you'd have to compile the code, walk the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), find the assignment, and then print the variable's `repr()` after running it.

Comment: So the iPython or python shell needs to do all this and the only solution is submit a feature request to the cpython or ipython project?

Comment: @hobs: [Abstract syntax tree.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) The stuff for dealing with it is in [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html).