# Showing assignment results in IPython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am writing a chain of equations/assignments from a heat transfer problem in ipython notebook (I am new to that one), like this:

```
# nominal diameter
d=3.55 # m
# ambient temperature
T0=15  # C
# surface temperature
Tw=300 # C
# average film temperature
Tm=(T0+Tw)/2+273.15 # K!
# expansion coefficient, $$\beta=1/T$$ for ideal gas
beta=1./Tm
# temperature difference
dT=Tw-T0 # C or K
```

Is there a way to echo each assignment, so that those (mostly computed) values are shown? I am aware of the `%whos` magic, but that shows variables alphabetically.

Ideally, I would like to get something like this:

```
# nominal diameter
d=3.55 # m
3.55
# ambient temperature
T0=15  # C
15
# surface temperature
Tw=300 # C
300
# average film temperature
Tm=(T0+Tw)/2+273.15 # K!
430.15
# expansion coefficient, $$\beta=1/T$$ for ideal gas
beta=1./Tm
0.00232477042892
# temperature difference
dT=Tw-T0 # C or K
285
```

perhaps with In/Out promps (I don't mind) and syntax-highlighted.

What is the proper way to document the computation this way with IPython?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ipython: automatically echo result of assignment statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273695/ipython-automatically-echo-result-of-assignment-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is [not](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/93) part of the core functionality of IPython. It has instead been incorporated into the extension [`displaytools`](https://github.com/cknoll/displaytools). Quote from the repo:

> Load this extension with `%load_ext displaytools` or `%reload_ext
>   displaytools`. The latter is useful for debugging.
>
> Example invocation:
>
> `my_random_variable = np.random.rand() ##`
>
> Due to the special comment `##` the extension inserts the line
>   `display(my_random_variable)` to the source code, before it is passed to
>   the interpreter, i.e. before its execution.
>
> That way, additional output is generated, which makes the notebook be
>   more comprehensible (because the reader knows the content of
>   `my_random_variable`). It saves the typing effort and the code
>   duplication of manually adding `display(my_random_variable)`.

Comment: `displaytools` is marked as deprecated and obsolete; its functionality is now part of [`ipydex`](https://github.com/cknoll/ipydex). Also, as of IPython 6.2, [there now is a built-in way to print assignment results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437791/ipython-magic-print-variables-on-assignment), at least when the target is a simple name.