# IPython magic print variables on assignment

Tags: python, ipython

Is there a parameter in IPython to print the variables each time I assign them?

Currently:

```
In [1]: a = 5

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 5

In [3]: b = a + 1

In [4]: b
Out[4]: 6
```

In [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), the variable is printed unless one writes a `;` at the end. In IPython, I would like to activate this with a magic function like so:

```
In [1]: %printassignment

In [2]: a = 5
a = 5

In [3]: b = a + 1
b = 6
```

I could write my own magic, but I'm pretty sure that's something that is so standard people would craft a super tuned, standard, function. The feature is especially useful for beginners.

Comment: After using `ipython` for some time, I find that MATLAB/Octave auto print to be a pain.  I keep forgetting the `;`.  If I want to see a calculation in Ipython I just omit the assignment.  I can always do `x=_` next if I want to save the displayed value.

Comment: I totally agree, that's why I don't say it should be the default, or even worse, I totally do not recommend it in scripts. However, I want to use it in my classes for young students, I really want to emphasize that the "python calculator" is as easy and intuitive as the "normal calculator". About x = _ I totally agree ! But then in the history when I write "x = "<UP> to recompute, I don't get the expression, I get _, which is not useful. Moreover when using it live in front of the students, it's easier for them to follow if they want to write down the intermediary values.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of IPython 6.2, [this exists](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version6.html#assignments-return-values), but the command to turn it on is really long:

```
%config InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity='last_expr_or_assign'
```

You can set it in your `ipython_config.py`, if you want it to be on by default:

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'last_expr_or_assign'
```

It only triggers when the assignment target is a simple name; assignments like `arr[i] = val` or `obj.attr = 3` will not auto-print.

Comment: +0 ... it's not really the same thing. Doesn't work like MATLAB.  Doesn't really work much at all, really (try it with setting an attribute).

Comment: @wim: How does it differ? I haven't been able to test it yet.

Comment: I've used it before, IIRC it just prints the RHS value for a plain old assignment statement.  *edit:*  apparently there's an [open issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10633) to make this feature work better, but nobody cares much.

Comment: @wim: Checking the [code](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10598/commits/a137755891640dc88d5a503970cd476201094e65), it looks like it's designed to only trigger when the assignment target is a simple name, perhaps because other assignment types are likely to do more complex things with whatever is assigned. (For example, after `float_arr[i] = some_int`, do you display `some_int` or `float_arr[i]`?) I don't know how MATLAB behaves, but I'll make a note in the answer.

Comment: It actually implements my other variation, write the result without printing the name :) ie. after a = 1 one have "_ == 1" whereas in the proposed version after writing 1+1 then a = 1 one sees "a = 1" (with the variable name) but "_" is still 2

Which it could be tunable :D

Comment: Also I noticed that if you add a `;` exactly like matlab it doesn't print :D And also that an expression like `a = 5; a` works and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following for older versions of IPython…

```
from IPython.core.inputtransformer import InputTransformer
import re

class PrintAssignment(InputTransformer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.assignment = re.compile('^([a-z]+) =')
        self.most_recent_line = None
    def push(self, line):
        self.most_recent_line = line
        return line
    def reset(self):
        if not self.most_recent_line: return
        match = self.assignment.match(self.most_recent_line)
        self.most_recent_line = None
        if match: return match.group(1)
```

And then register this input handler with

```
ip = get_ipython()
ip.physical_line_transforms.append(PrintAssignment())
```