# IPython display assignment result

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, assign

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4273695/3646263) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32839954/3646263).

I'm curious however how the following line of a [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) on the Matplotlib website can be reproduced:

[image]

That is, if I where to accept the explanation of the answers of the questions linked above, this should not be possible. 
Both answers state that displaying an assignment result is not part of the core functionality of IPython. The second answer suggests a workaround by using the [`displaytools`](https://github.com/cknoll/displaytools) extension, which requires you to append the assignment line to be displayed by `##`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can take the tutorial literally. In reality this would look like

```
In [5]: img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')

In [6]: img
Out[6]: 
array([[[ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
        [ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
        [ 0.40784314,  0.40784314,  0.40784314],
```

in IPython. The reason it looks different in the tutorial is that it is automatically formatted from a sourcecode. The [source of this part](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6582a9dfd7a0076e1ee3efab58f21545facf6107/tutorials/introductory/images.py#L81) looks like

```
# It's a 24-bit RGB PNG image (8 bits for each of R, G, B).  Depending
# on where you get your data, the other kinds of image that you'll most
# likely encounter are RGBA images, which allow for transparency, or
# single-channel grayscale (luminosity) images.  You can right click on
# it and choose "Save image as" to download it to your computer for the
# rest of this tutorial.
#
# And here we go...

img = mpimg.imread('../../doc/_static/stinkbug.png')
print(img)

###############################################################################
# Note the dtype there - float32.  Matplotlib has rescaled the 8 bit
# data from each channel to floating point data between 0.0 and 1.0.
```

The `print` statement somehow translates into `Out[5]`.

Comment: Yes, obviously, calling the object will output it. I would find it highly misleading if they where to hard-code this non-existent behavior into a tutorial. I mean, an output is a result of an instruction; in this case calling some object. Why would the author possibly want to fabricate an output-syntax which isn't reproducible? The `Out[#outputnumber]` syntax does have a meaning; a response to instruction `In[#instruction-number]`.

Comment: Actually, I found the reason. See updated answer. In any case, you can always file a issue at the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) if you really think it is confusing. (I have read this tutorial a couple of times already and it never occured to me that this is actually not working as stated there.)

Comment: Actually you can use the --TerminalInteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity=... to `all` or `last_expr_or_assign` to get the shown behavior; though it is an advance option that should only be used if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Matt Case still being that they "hard-coded" that line in the tutorial, which isn't didactically sound. I made a pull request to replace the `print(img)` line by a direct invocation of the object by just calling `img`.

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out that you technically can but yes I agree that didactically it's not the best. Thanks for the PR though on MPL though.